# Blue Water Coming out of Faucets

Tags: plumbing

About a year ago I had light blue water coming out of the faucets from the back 1/2 of the house, it stopped after a day and the plumber couldn't find anything wrong. Fast forward one year later, I changed the water filter (NuvoH20) and it started happening again - this time from all the faucets in the house, the water is also darker and leaving blue water deposits (much like hard water). I'm having the plumber come out and check for copper corrosion but am wondering if anyone has recommendations as far as what else to look for. Please see attached photo of toilet water. Thanks.[image]

Comment: A quick Google search indicated this is a common issue with that filter/softener system and one site said it was harmless. You might want to check with the manufacturer.

Comment: Copper plumbing has this issue especially with softeners and water with high mineral counts. That should be a answer.